# DOMPurify for XSS

Tags: javascript, html, url, xss, dompurify

I am trying to fix the cross side scripting (XSS) with the DOMPurify . The vulnerability found is in the URL as below .
[https://stage-xyzmysite.com/login/?rUrl=javascript:alert('hi')](https://stage-xyzmysite.com/login/?rUrl=javascript:alert(%27hi%27)) . I am trying to do a simple POC where it will try to eliminate the javascript alert part . I tried with DOMPurify.sanitize(< the url here > ) . I am expecting to see the javascript part getting removed but it is not happening . If I enclose the alert with  tag in the URL then it is getting eliminated. Is there any other special config I should be using ?

Comment: DOMPurify is for cleaning HTML. You have an untrusted URL, not HTML; you should validate its scheme (`http` or `https`, or if it’s supposed to be an internal redirect you should go even further and make sure it’s to your own site) before creating a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

DOMPurify cleans your HTML, it has to be HTML for there to be any risk of anyone clicking the link. If you just print it like text there is no risk of a user clicking on the link and getting injected.

Here is an article about XSS in HTML with examples on how to use DOMPurify in case it helps you https://writingjavascript.com/keep-your-html-output-secure-and-clean-from-xss-javascript-injection